# HTML Div cannot be hidden when it is inside a table

Tags: html, html-table, hide, show

I have a table like this:

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr >

        <div id="div_1c">
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td class="t15CurrentTabCenter"><span>Urlap megjegyzések</span></td>
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        </div>

        <div id="div_1nc">
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td class="t15TabCenter" onclick="zfocus_Div('DIV_MEGJEGYZES','div_1c')" ><a href="#TAB_LINK#">Urlap megjegyzések</a></td>
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close.gif" alt="" /></td>
        </div>

        <div id="div_2c">
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td class="t15CurrentTabCenter"><span>Üzemviteli munkák</span></td>
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        </div>

        <div id="div_2nc">
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open.gif" alt="" /></td>
            <td class="t15TabCenter" onclick="zfocus_Div('DIV_UZEMVITELI_MUNKA','div_2c')"><a href="#TAB_LINK#">Üzemviteli munkák</a></td>
            <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close.gif" alt="" /></td>
        </div>

      </tr>
</table>
```

Plus some Javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function zfocus_Div(pActiveTab,pActiveDiv)
{
   html_HideElement('AAA');
   html_HideElement('div_1c');
   html_HideElement('div_2nc');
   html_HideElement('div_2c');

   html_HideElement('DIV_MEGJEGYZES');
   html_HideElement('DIV_UZEMVITELI_MUNKA');

   html_ShowElement(pActiveTab); 
   html_ShowElement(pActiveDiv);   
}

</script>
```

I execute the following code in the onload event of the page:

```
<script> zfocus_Div('DIV_MEGJEGYZES','div_1c') </script>
```

After the execution, none of the divs in the table get hidden. Can somebody please explain what the cause for this might be?  As far as I know, the divs can be used within a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `div` elements will actually end up outside the `table`.

You can't have `div` elements (or any non-table elements) inside a table except inside `td` or `th` elements. If you try that, the browser will try to correct the code, either by removing the illegal elements, or move them outside the table.

Answer (score 1):

As Guffa wrote, `<div>` elements will dissapear, because you put them between `<tr>` and `<td>` elements (choose **View source** option in your browser, to see rendered html code).

Try to place them inside `<td>` elements, like this:

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr >
        <td>
            <div id="div_1c">
                <img src="bookmark.gif" alt="" />
                <span class="t15CurrentTabCenter">Urlap megjegyzések</span>
                <img src="bookmark.gif"" alt="" />
            </div>
         </td>       
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not change the table structure from

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you want to write any content please keep inside td

and you code will be like this

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr id="div_1c" >
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="t15CurrentTabCenter"><span>Urlap megjegyzések</span></td>
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="div_1nc">
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="t15TabCenter" onclick="zfocus_Div('DIV_MEGJEGYZES','div_1c')" ><a href="#TAB_LINK#">Urlap megjegyzések</a></td>
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="div_2c">
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="t15CurrentTabCenter"><span>Üzemviteli munkák</span></td>
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close_c.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="div_2nc">
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_open.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td class="t15TabCenter" onclick="zfocus_Div('DIV_UZEMVITELI_MUNKA','div_2c')"><a href="#TAB_LINK#">Üzemviteli munkák</a></td>
        <td><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#themes/theme_15/tab_close.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tr>
</table>
```

and are you doing anything with this function name "html_HideElement" to hide ?